# openni_launch doesn't work with kinect

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

Working in Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 I cannot get my kinect to work when using

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

It only gives

```
[ INFO] [1457006309.632299424]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

But the kinect is working perfectly with

```
roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch
```

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance, Sietse

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228100/openni_launch-doesn%27t-work-with-kinect/) by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2016-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that I didn't read the documentation of the ROS package openni_camera properly:(.

In that documentation there is a section: Use Kinect on Ubuntu with OpenNI

In a blog that is referred to it is described that you have to install a special version of openni and a sensor module.

I followed the recipe and it works!

---

Originally posted by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) with karma: 168 on 2016-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0